# How to use displaylink adapter with ubuntu 18.4.4

Tags: drivers, usb, multiple-monitors, displaylink

I have installed the ubuntu driver software for display link adapter and followed the instructions at:

https://support.displaylink.com/know...on-legacy-ubun

However, Whenever I connect my usb 3.0 to dvi/vga adapter - ubuntu does not recognise a screen is attached.

I am using the following adapter:

https://www.kensington.com/p/product...splay-adapter/

The adapter does appear when using the
Code:

```
lsusb
yields the result:
Code:
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 17e9:430f DisplayLink
```

So I know that it has recognised the displaylink on the USB bus.

I have also run the DL support Tool found at:

https://support.displaylink.com/know...to-displaylink

I have been trying for weeks to get this working and it's really frustrating - hopefully someone can help me out here, I just want to be able to use another monitor via my usb3.0 port and purchased this Kensington adapter to do so - but alas it's not working.

If anyone can give me some advice or help I would be grateful!

I am using ubuntu 18.4.4 for reference.

I did cross post this on the actual displaylink forum but stuck for help at the moment!

Comment: All three links are resulting in 404 errors (page not found).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new driver at displaylink fixed my display issues.  I have an ASUS and Nvidia drivers.  After upgrading to Focal Fossa my dual displays stopped working; but, the latest driver 5.3.1.34 fixed the issues.  Just remember to extract the file then right click on properties to enable it to run as an executable.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by following the instructions on:

https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu

and disabling secure boot.